# How to move CSS from a '::before' selector into React?

Tags: css, reactjs, css-selectors

I have a program that creates a small robot that moves around on an isometric grid.

[image: correct robot on map]

Each tile is an image, and the robot is a superimposed image, created using a `::before` selector:

```
.robot::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url("https://femto.pw/us7j.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The source code for the CSS project can be found [here](https://codepen.io/codefined/pen/xxVgexZ).

I want to convert the CSS so that it is styled within the 'react' component that creates it.  I create a `span` before the background div element and put in the CSS there to pretend to be "::before" the element.  The code to create a tile goes from:

```
  <td style={{transform: `translateX(${x * 4}em)`}}>
    <div className="tile">
      <div className={"background" + (robot ? ' robot' : '')} />
    </div>
  </td>
```

to

```
  <td style={{transform: `translateX(${x * 4}em)`}}>
    <div className="tile">
      {robot &&
        <span style={{
          "content": "''",
          "position": "absolute",
          "top": "-40px",
          "bottom": "0",
          "left": "0",
          "right": "0",
          "backgroundImage": "url(\"https://femto.pw/us7j.png\")",
          "backgroundSize": "contain",
          "backgroundRepeat": "no-repeat"
          }} />
        }
      <div className="background" />
    </div>
  </td>
```

The code for the project at this point can be found [here](https://codepen.io/codefined/pen/yLOgrYW).

However, when I make this change, which I *thought* should be identical, it looks totally different!

[image: weird robot on grid]

What is happening?  How can I convert the CSS to work in React (which doesn't have CSS selectors like that)?

Comment: The problem is that the `::before` element used to be on the `background robot` div which has `height` and `width` applied so the positioning, width and height of the `::before` element had values to style against. Since you moved everything to the span, there is nothing telling that element how to size. Move the span element inside of the `background` to test: https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/XWdpQVd

Comment: That's exceptional and works so well!  Would you like to copy that into an answer so I can mark it correct? :)

Comment: Yeah! Added and answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `::before` element used to be on the `background robot` div which has height and width applied so the positioning, width and height of the `::before` element had values to style against.

Since you moved everything to the `span`, there is nothing telling that element how to size.

Here's an updated pen with the `span` moved to the `background` div:

https://codepen.io/chrislafrombois/pen/XWdpQVd

Here's the code that changed:

```
const CreateTile = (x, robot) => (
  <td style={{transform: `translateX(${x * 4}em)`}}>
    <div className="tile">
      
      <div className="background">
        {robot &&
        <span style={{
          "content": "''",
          "position": "absolute",
          "top": "-40px",
          "bottom": "0",
          "left": "0",
          "right": "0",
          "backgroundImage": "url(\"https://femto.pw/us7j.png\")",
          "backgroundSize": "contain",
          "backgroundRepeat": "no-repeat"
          }} />
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you forget to add some style coming from the `.background.robot` older parent:

```css
.robot {
    transform: rotateZ(-45deg) rotateY(-60deg) translate3d(-1.1em, -4.8em, 0em);
    height: calc(23em);
    width: calc(23em);
}
```

Just add them to the span with a `z-index: 1;` and you will have the original result. Just see it in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/johannchopin/pen/MWyJRBw).

Comment: That's also a good solution!  I've accepted the other answer and think I'll keep it marked as a solution because it removes any duplication of styling.  Thanks for the alternative though :)

Comment: Yeah sure no problem ;) But if it's a good solution it can also get an `upvote` right? :)

Comment: Hell yeah! @johannchopin :)